# Using FFMPEG, how does one manage to find the file to convert?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

[image]

I've been trying to get FFMPEG to do a conversion of this file because I was bored, but FFMPEG can't seem to find the file, the location tags that I have before the file name were found by dragging and dropping the file into CMD. The other code I'm getting from one of the other boards [How do I turn audio into video (that is, show the waveforms in a video)?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/how-do-i-turn-audio-into-video-that-is-show-the-waveforms-in-a-video)

Answer (score 4):

If a filename or its folder has spaces or other special characters, you need to enclose it in quotes i.e.

`ffmpeg -i "c:\this\file name\and path\has\spaces in it.mp4" ...`